# ActiveMQ message transfer timing

Tags: time, jms, message, activemq-classic

In ActiveMQ, Can I anyway detect how much time a message took to deliver to subscriber from a publisher?
Or Can I see separate timings that message took go from Publisher to topic(JMS service) And from (JMS service)Topic to Subsriber?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [Maven plugin for AMQ performance testing](http://activemq.apache.org/activemq-performance-module-users-manual.html), it might be what you are searching for.

Otherwise, you could come very far by doing some measurements with some load testing tool such as [Apache jMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) and just see how many messages you can read/write / sec.

Notice that you will have rather big differences if you go persistent and/or transactional or not.

Update:

You could maybe do something with the log by configuring conf/log4j.properties and setting:

```
log4j.rootLogger=TRACE, logfile, console
```

Then in data/activemq.log you can get some information for a put message. It's not really obvious what the numbers represent, so you should make sure to define a test scenario. The following time stamps was from a message put to a queue (myqueue) by HermesJMS to ActiveMQ:

```
2012-06-06 16:31:19,979 | DEBUG | localhost adding consumer: ID:GOTL19946-53234-
1338993070006-0:2:3:1 for destination: queue://myqueue |org.apache.activemq.broker.region.AbstractRegion | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///127.0.0.1:53236
2012-06-06 16:31:19,989 | DEBUG | queue://myqueue add sub: QueueBrowserSubscription: consumer=ID:GOTL19946-53234-1338993070006-0:2:3:1, destinations=0, dispatched=0, delivered=0, pending=0, dequeues: 0, dispatched: 0, inflight: 0 | org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///127.0.0.1:53236
2012-06-06 16:31:19,989 | DEBUG | myqueue toPageIn: 1, Inflight: 0, pagedInMessages.size 0, enqueueCount: 1, dequeueCount: 0 | org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue | Queue:myqueue
2012-06-06 16:31:19,989 | TRACE | QueueStorePrefetch513024249 - fillBatch | org.apache.activemq.broker.region.cursors.AbstractStoreCursor | Queue:myqueue
2012-06-06 16:31:19,989 | DEBUG | dispatch to browser: QueueBrowserSubscription: consumer=ID:GOTL19946-53234-1338993070006-0:2:3:1, destinations=1, dispatched=0, delivered=0, pending=0, already dispatched/paged count: 1 | org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue | Queue:myqueue
2012-06-06 16:31:19,999 | TRACE | ID:GOTL19946-53234-1338993070006-0:2:3:1 dispatched: ID:GOTL19946-53234-1338993070006-0:2:2:1:1 - queue://myqueue, dispatched: 1, inflight: 1 | org.apache.activemq.broker.region.PrefetchSubscription | ActiveMQ Connection Dispatcher: /127.0.0.1:53236
2012-06-06 16:31:19,999 | TRACE | ack:MessageAck {commandId = 13, responseRequired = false, ackType = 2, consumerId = ID:GOTL19946-53234-1338993070006-0:2:3:1, firstMessageId = ID:GOTL19946-53234-1338993070006-0:2:2:1:1, lastMessageId = ID:GOTL19946-53234- 1338993070006-0:2:2:1:1, destination = queue://myqueue, transactionId = TX:ID:GOTL19946-  53234-1338993070006-0:2:2, messageCount = 1, poisonCause = null} | org.apache.activemq.broker.region.PrefetchSubscription | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///127.0.0.1:53236
2012-06-06 16:31:19,999 | DEBUG | commit: TX:ID:GOTL19946-53234-1338993070006-0:2:2 syncCount: 1 | org.apache.activemq.transaction.LocalTransaction | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///127.0.0.1:53236
2012-06-06 16:31:19,999 | DEBUG | myqueue toPageIn: 0, Inflight: 1, pagedInMessages.size 1, enqueueCount: 1, dequeueCount: 0 | org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue | Queue:myqueue
2012-06-06 16:31:20,049 | DEBUG | localhost removing consumer: ID:GOTL19946-53234-1338993070006-0:2:3:1 for destination: queue://myqueue | org.apache.activemq.broker.region.AbstractRegion | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///127.0.0.1:53236
2012-06-06 16:31:20,049 | DEBUG | queue://myqueue remove sub: QueueBrowserSubscription: consumer=ID:GOTL19946-53234-1338993070006-0:2:3:1, destinations=1, dispatched=0, delivered=1, pending=0, lastDeliveredSeqId: 67, dequeues: 0, dispatched: 1, inflight: 0 | org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///127.0.0.1:53236
2012-06-06 16:31:20,049 | DEBUG | myqueue toPageIn: 0, Inflight: 0, pagedInMessages.size 1, enqueueCount: 1, dequeueCount: 0 | org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue | Queue:myqueue
```

Comment: ok. So no code level debugging can be added, atlest to get average time n all for message transfer ?

Comment: Added some info how to sample debug output from activemq log. Not sure if that is what you want.

Answer (score 3):

When JMS message arrives at the consumer, you can look into the `JMSTimestamp` header property. According to the Javadoc:

> The JMSTimestamp header field contains the time a message was handed
>   off to be sent.

Then you can simply subtract JMSTimestamp from current system time and calculate the `time taken` in flight by that JMS message.